# how do i do redirect on php with form resulting in values in url?

Tags: php, html

i am using php and this is my form

```
<form method="POST" action="www.welcome.php"style="clear:both">
<legend>Login</legend>
Username: <input type="text" name="username" size="20"  id="username" class="content"     /><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="password" size="20"  id="password" class="content"  /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" class="content" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" class="content" />
<div id="login_response"></div>

</form>
```

however, i want the redirected page url to be

```
www.welcome.php?username=xxxx
```

provided i logged in with xxxx

Comment: So method="get"? I can't see the interest…

Comment: I think you need to learn some basic understanding of POST and GET.  See some of the links in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290856/how-getpageno-works-in-php-pagination/7290896#7290896

Answer (score 0):

> i want the redirected page url to be www.welcome.php?username=xxxx

for the form's action you don't need it. Just leave your form as is.

if you want to redirect a user *after* the form processing (as you have to anyway), just add an entered username to the URL in the Location header:

```
header("Location: welcome.php?username=".$_POST['username']);
exit;
```

Answer (score -1):

As posted in the second comment, form method="GET" will send the user over to this URL: www.welcome.com/?username=xxxx&password=yyyyyy

However, assuming you do not want the URL to have the password in the querystring (bad idea!) then you will have to submit the form with Javascript, in order to pass the username in the querystring and the password in the post variables. Specifically, your submit button should have an onclick event that calls a Javascript function, which then reads the value of the username and appends it to the action URL, then submits the whole form with the POST method.

I can't think of a reason why you would want the username to be in the querystring instead of the post variables though.

In MB The Developer's answer, the www.welcome.com?username=xxxx URL is hardcoded, which doesn't seem that useful, but if you are talking about a failed login going back to the login page ("redirected?") then MB's example could be extended with something like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="www.welcome.com?username=<?php print($_GET['username']); ?>"style="clear:both">
```

Also I think you will want your password field to be type="password" instead of type="text".